# Unable to create procedures in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Can someone help me to create stored procedure?

I am unable to create the stored procedure in my phpmyadmin. MySQL version is  5.6.17. When I try to create the procedure with phpmyadmin interface I am getting error message like below:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

Below is the procedure I am trying to create.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getUsers(IN id INT)
```

When I am trying to create command line below is the error I am getting.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'CREAT E PROCEDURE getAdmins(IN id INT)

Comment: not sure if this is the problem, but CREATE has a space between CREAT & E

Comment: Sorry, in my query there is no space between T & E, In error message it shows some space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE getUsers(IN id INT)
    BEGIN
    // Query, if there
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```